# How to parse text from html using lxml?

Tags: python, text, xpath, lxml

```
<p>
    Glassware veteran
    <strong>Corning </strong>
    (
    <span class="ticker">
      NYSE:
      <a class="qsAdd qs-source-isssitthv0000001" href="http://caps.fool.com/Ticker/GLW.aspx?source=isssitthv0000001" data-id="203758">GLW</a>
    </span>
    <a class="addToWatchListIcon qsAdd qs-source-iwlsitbut0000010" href="http://my.fool.com/watchlist/add?ticker=&source=iwlsitbut0000010" title="Add to My Watchlist"> </a>
    ) has fallen on hard times lately. Is it time to give up on the stock, or will Corning have a banana and a comeback?
</p>
```

I want to get "Glassware veteran" and "has fallen on hard times lately. Is it time to give up on the stock, or will Corning have a banana and a comeback?"

Using the code

```
tnode = root.xpath("/p")
content = tnode.text
```

I can only get "Glassware veteran",why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might get you what you want:

```
>>> tnode = root.xpath('/p')
>>> content = tnode.xpath('text()')
>>> print ''.join(content)

Glassware veteran

(


) has fallen on hard times lately. Is it time to give up on the stock, or will Corning have a banana and a comeback?
>>>
```

If you want *all* of the text nodes, just use `//text()` instead of `text()`:

```
>>> print ' '.join([x.strip() for x in ele.xpath('//text()')])
Glassware veteran Corning ( NYSE: GLW    ) has fallen on hard times lately. Is it time to give up on the stock, or will Corning have a banana and a comeback?
```

Comment: Thank you very much.But now I have a new problem,I want to get "Glassware veteran Corning (NYSE: GLW  ) has fallen on hard times lately. Is it time to give up on the stock, or will Corning have a banana and a comeback?"    Using the code: tnode = root.xpath('/p | /p/strong | /p/a | /p/span')   content = tnode.xpath('text()')  print ''.join(content)     The result is "Glassware veteran  ( )  has fallen on hard times lately. Is it time to give up on the stock, or will Corning have a banana and a comeback?  Corning NYSE: 
GLW "  Do you have some ideas? Thanks.